# Program not printing out numbers

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C and I bought the book "The C programming language" and started reading and doing everything it says. There is a code in the book which should print out the number of lines,words and characters of a sentence. This is the code of the book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */


/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
 int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

 state = OUT;
 nl = nw = nc = 0;
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      ++nc;
      if (c == '\n')
          ++nl; 
      if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
          state = OUT;
      else if (state == OUT) {
          state = IN;
          ++nw;
      }
 }
printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

For some reason the values that should be printed out with the printf aren't shown. I really don't know what is wrong. It only prints out numbers if I put the printf in the while loop but this can't be right because it prints the numbers every time the values change.

Comment: It looks alright to me. What happens if you throw it into a debugger and put a breakpoint on the printf you're waiting for it to get to. Is it possible that the printf is executing and then the command window closes before you actually see the output? Try adding a getchar() after the printf.

Comment: Note that you have written c = '\t' instead of c == '\t'.

Comment: That must be a typo of the book. I also put a getchar() after the printf but nothing happens.

Comment: More important than that (==): which system are you using and how did you run your program?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in this line -- the assignment of `c = '\t'` always evaluates to true

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

To fix, change = to ==

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
```

To answer your question **why does it not print anything out** -- I think that the compiler is either giving your an error or warning causing the program not being linked, and hence you are not actually compiling the source code as listed, but rather you are running an old version of whatever code you compiled before.

Comment: This demonstrates exactly why many of us would write that as: `if (' ' ==c || '\n' == c || '\t' == c)` -- if you accidentally mis-type the comparison as an assignment, you'll get a compiler error. Of course, `if (isspace(c))` would be better still.

Comment: Correct but harder to read, as it is not the way we would say it.   Most compiler (such as modern versions of gcc) gives an warning on this.

Comment: I found it a bit jarring at first, but that disappeared after a few weeks or so. Personally, I prefer something that always works with every compiler to something that might with some versions of some compilers, but can be disabled even with them.

Answer (score 1):

gcc gives a compile error on this line:

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

looking @ that line, it's easy to spot a typo: `c = '\t')`

missing an equality test, no?
:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are reading your input from STDIN (the keyboard) and leave the loop only on "End of file", which will not happen. Do as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo others have mentioned, you need to send an End-Of-File signal to end the input loop. This will depend on the environment you are running it - will be Ctrl+Z in Windows, and should be Ctrl+D in *NIX environments. I needed to enter this on a new line and press Enter afterwards when using my usual IDE (Code::Blocks).

[image: What it looks like]

Remember too that at the time K&R (1 & 2) was written, command line programming was the norm, and typically you would expect the output to be visible if you just ended the program. Some IDEs will close their terminal emulator at the end of the program before you can view the results, so you may need to add something like

```
printf("\nPress return to continue");
getchar();
```

at the end of the program. Or, run it yourself from the OS terminal emulator (using cmd.exe on Windows, or gnome-terminal, yakuake, or whatever your OS provides). Navigate to the folder and

```
your_executable.exe
```

or

```
./your_executable
```

Comment: And you might actually have to add a second getchar() if you do need to do this, as there will probably be a newline char still in the stream

Answer (score 0):

it was a equality issue as pointed above in `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')`.
I would suggest you use a good IDE like [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) which warns you of such bugs .